# error execute app with expo react native when update of sdk 38 to 39

Tags: react-native, sdk, expo

my app developed with react native sdk 38 worked good but i update the sdk to 39 and mi app show this error

this is the error displayed on my terminal.
Unable to resolve "./environment/mutewarnings.fx" from "node_modules\expo\build\Expo.Fx.expo.js

i´m working with s.o windows 10.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote this command

```
expo r -c
```

and my app run without errors

Comment: you might want to clarify that this is an expo cli command